# Quoting sources and copyright issues

Tags: discusión, legal-issues

Many good answers here so far have involved quotations from dictionaries, RAE publications, etc. What should people keep in mind in terms of copyright rules and legal issues when quoting like this? Are there any rules of thumb for when and how it's appropriate (and legal) to quote?

Comment: It is a matter of Fair Use. See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64627/is-quoting-a-book-in-a-question-or-answer-copyright-violation) on Meta.Stackoverflow.